# Ruby on Rails insertando datos extras en una tabla join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, orm

Estoy tratando de insertar a la hora de crear un registro, atributos adicionales en la tabla join, lo que creo que no esta bien es como enviarlos hacia el controlador o como acceder a ellos para crear el registro en la bd.

la tabla en la bd es:

```
create_table "section_profesor_subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.bigint "profesor_subject_id"
 t.bigint "section_id"
 t.string "day"
 t.decimal "time_init"
 t.decimal "time_end"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.index ["profesor_subject_id"], name: "index_section_profesor_subjects_on_profesor_subject_id"
 t.index ["section_id"], name: "index_section_profesor_subjects_on_section_id"
end
```

Los modelos son:

section.rb

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
 #Users
 has_many :user_sections, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :user_sections

 #Profesores y Materias
 has_many :section_profesor_subjects, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :profesor_subjects, through: :section_profesor_subjects
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :section_profesor_subjects, allow_destroy: true

 validates :description, presence: { message: 'La seccion debe de tener una descripcion' }

end
```

profesor_subject.rb

```
class ProfesorSubject < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :subject


 has_many :section_profesor_subjects, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :sections, through: :section_profesor_subjects
end
```

section_profesor_subject.rb

```
class SectionProfesorSubject < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :profesor_subject
 belongs_to :section
end
```

section_controller.rb  Accion para crear

```
def create
 @section = Section.new(section_params)
 #respond_to do |format|
 if params[:section_profesor_subjects_attributes]
   if @section.save
     params[:section_profesor_subjects_attributes]['section_profesor_subject'].each do |spsa|
       i = spsa.split(',').length
       @profesor_subject_id = (spsa.split(',')[i-i]).to_i
       @day = (spsa.split(',')[$i - ($i - 1)]).to_s
       @time_init = (spsa.split(',')[$i - ($i - 2)]).to_f
       @time_end = (spsa.split(',')[$i - ($i - 3)]).to_f
       @section.section_profesor_subjects.create!(:profesor_subject_id => @profesor_subject_id, :day => @day, :time_init => @time_init, :time_end => @time_end )
     end
     redirect_to admin_sections_path
   else
     flash.now[:danger] = "Seccion no creada: "+(@section.errors.full_messages).to_s
     redirect_to admin_sections_path
   end
 else
   flash.now[:danger] = "Seccion no creada: "+(@section.errors.full_messages).to_s
   redirect_to admin_sections_path
 end    
end

def section_params
  params.require(:section).permit(:description, user_ids: [], section_profesor_subjects_attributes: [])
end
```

La forma en la que estoy tratando de enviar los atributos es la siguiente:

```
<input class="dt4input'+id_unique+'" readonly="readonly" name="section[section_profesor_subjects_attributes][]" value="'+valor+'"/>
```

De esta forma voy creando cada array con la información que necesito para ser agregada a la base de datos, cada input tiene los valores que necesito, mas sin embargo no lo logro realizar, agradezco también cualquier otra forma en la que pueda almacenar la información.

Los parámetros que están enviado son (Teniendo especial atención en "section_profesor_subjects_attributes") :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8+d8lpwpS8lUh0bdVcPno5Jbz7Ap4K2DWaYG3vu/bbK+2vtCTZX4+d6JuRUp0xL/Aut3dITd36KQHzewowIgxQ==", "section"=>{"description"=>"5to grado", "user_ids"=>["2", "11", "5"], "section_profesor_subjects_attributes"=>["1,Lunes,7,8", "2,Martes,9,10"]}, "dataTable_length"=>"10", "dataTable2_length"=>"10", "dataTable3_length"=>"10", "dataTable4_length"=>"10", "commit"=>"Create Section"}
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿puedes agregar el log completo de cuando realizas el post? para ver los parámetros enviados y si sale algún mensaje que algún parámetro no está permitido

Comment: Pregunta editada, agregue los parámetros, estoy tratando de esta manera de salvar los datos, pero nada, me arroja el error (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer).

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás usando nested attributes, usa el helper 
[fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) para generar los inputs y Rails se encargará del resto.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución no tan a mi gusto pero que funciona, ya que lo ideal que deseaba era enviar como parámetros parte de section los atributos extras de la tabla join que es section_profesor_subjects en un array, y no obtenerlos como parte los parámetros que envío al controlador desde la vista.

en el controlador section.rb

```
def create
 @section = Section.new(section_params)
 if params[:section_profesor_subjects]
   if @section.save

     $i
     @profesor_subject_id
     @day
     @time_init
     @time_end

     params[:section_profesor_subjects].each do |spsa|
       $i = spsa.split(',').length
       @profesor_subject_id = (spsa.split(',')[$i-$i]).to_i
       @day = (spsa.split(',')[$i - ($i - 1)]).to_s
       @time_init = (spsa.split(',')[$i - ($i - 2)]).to_f
       @time_end = (spsa.split(',')[$i - ($i - 3)]).to_f

       SectionProfesorSubject.create!(:profesor_subject_id => @profesor_subject_id, :section_id => @section.id, :day => @day, :time_init => @time_init, :time_end => @time_end)
     end

     flash[:success] = "Seccion Creada Exitosamente"
     redirect_to admin_sections_path
   else
     flash[:danger] = @section.errors.full_messages
   end  
 else
   flash[:danger] = "No encontre parametros"
   redirect_to new_admin_section_path
 end  
end


def section_params
  params.require(:section).permit(:description, user_ids: [])
end
```

el input también tiene un cambio a la hora de renombrar el parámetro, considero importante destacar que estos son creados de forma dinámica con jquery

```
<input class="dt4input'+id_unique+'" readonly="readonly" name="section_profesor_subjects[]" value="'+valor+'"/>
```